# How to make JOOQ gradle script does not re-create classes for which the table has not changed?

Tags: java, jooq

I have this gradle script for auto generate JOOQ classes.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(
                'org.jooq:jooq:3.18.4',
                'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.18.4',
                'org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.18.4',
                'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0'
        )
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'nu.studer.jooq'

import org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.*

task generateJooq {
    def configuration = new Configuration()
            .withJdbc(
                    new Jdbc()
                            .withDriver('org.postgresql.Driver')
                            .withUrl('jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test')
                            .withUser('postgres')
                            .withPassword('password'))
            .withGenerator(
                    new Generator()
                            .withDatabase(new Database().withExcludes("databasechangeloglock|databasechangelog").withInputSchema("public"))
                            .withGenerate(
                                    new Generate()
                                            .withRoutines(false)
                                            .withPojos(true)
                                            .withDaos(true)
                            ).withTarget(
                            new Target()
                                    .withPackageName('com.example.model.jooq')
                                    .withDirectory(projectDir.toString() + '/src/main/java')
                    ).withStrategy(
                            new Strategy()
                                    .withMatchers(
                                            new Matchers()
                                                    .withTables(
                                                            new MatchersTableType()
                                                                    .withTableIdentifier(
                                                                            new MatcherRule()
                                                                                    .withExpression('$0_Entity')
                                                                                    .withTransform(MatcherTransformType.UPPER)
                                                                    ).withPojoClass(new MatcherRule().withExpression('$0_Entity').withTransform(MatcherTransformType.PASCAL))
                                                    )
                                    )
                    )
            )

    doLast {
        GenerationTool.generate(configuration)
    }
}
```

But when I make any changes to the tables (for example, do migration), I need to change my pojo, records, etc. classes. And when I run task `generateJooq`, it delete all classes and re-create their, and the **problem is that all the lombok annotations (data, builder) disappear.**
I would like that when running the task, JOOQ would re-create only the changed tables, or even better if it did not re-create, and only added new fields in existing classes.

Comment: After a long search, I understand that can use a method JavaGenerator.printClassAnnotations(JavaWriter, Definition, GeneratorStrategy.Mode), but I didn’t understand what arguments to pass there. what file should I pass there? Please give example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lukas Eder, but I didn't figure it out :) and wrote this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(
                'org.jooq:jooq:3.18.4',
                'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.18.4',
                'org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.18.4',
                'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0'
        )
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'nu.studer.jooq'


import org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.*

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths

task generateJooq {
    var database = new Database().withExcludes("databasechangeloglock|databasechangelog").withInputSchema("public")
    def configuration = new Configuration()
            .withJdbc(
                    new Jdbc()
                            .withDriver('org.postgresql.Driver')
                            .withUrl('jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test')
                            .withUser('postgres')
                            .withPassword('bigdata8'))
            .withGenerator(
                    new Generator()
                            .withDatabase(database)
                            .withGenerate(
                                    new Generate()
                                            .withRoutines(false)
                                            .withPojos(true)
                                            .withDaos(true)
                            )
                            .withTarget(
                                    new Target()
                                            .withPackageName('com.example.model.jooq')
                                            .withDirectory(projectDir.toString() + '/src/main/java')
                            )
                            .withStrategy(
                                    new Strategy()
                                            .withMatchers(
                                                    new Matchers()
                                                            .withTables(
                                                                    new MatchersTableType()
                                                                            .withTableIdentifier(
                                                                                    new MatcherRule()
                                                                                            .withExpression('$0_Entity')
                                                                                            .withTransform(MatcherTransformType.UPPER)
                                                                            ).withPojoClass(new MatcherRule().withExpression('$0_Entity').withTransform(MatcherTransformType.PASCAL))
                                                            )
                                            )
                            )
            )


    doLast {
        GenerationTool.generate(configuration)

        Files.walk(Paths.get(srcDir() + 'com/example/model/jooq/tables/pojos'))
                .filter(path -> Files.isRegularFile(path))
                .forEach(path -> {
                    List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(path)

                    boolean importAdded = false
                    boolean annotationsAdded = false
                    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        if (list.get(i - 1).startsWith("import") && list.get(i) == "") {
                            list.add(i + 1, "import lombok.Builder;")
                            i += 2
                            importAdded = true
                        }
                        if (importAdded) {
                            if (list.get(i).startsWith("public class")) {
                                list.add(i - 1, "@Builder")
                                annotationsAdded = true
                                break
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (!importAdded || !annotationsAdded) {
                        throw new RuntimeException()
                    }

                    Files.write(path, list, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                })
    }
}

String srcDir() {
    return projectDir.path + "/src/main/java/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ's code generator doesn't touch files whose contents haven't changed, to enable incremental compilation. But this obviously only works if you don't touch generated code (including if you override the code generator to behave differently, which is OK).

If you change generated code *after* jOOQ generated it, there's no way for jOOQ to know that you're doing that. There's also no way for jOOQ to know that the changes of an existing file originated from your manual intervention, or from a previous jOOQ version, or whatever. The new output simply differs from the existing content, so jOOQ has to overwrite the file.

Now, changing generated code manually is simply *never* a good idea for the above reasons. If you *have to* make changes to generated code, you should either:

- Use official extension points of the `JavaGenerator`, e.g. for [custom code sections](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code/)
- Extend the `JavaGenerator` and override some of its behaviour
- Use some automated post processing, e.g. using regular expression search/replace

In the latter case, again, jOOQ won't be able to recognise your changes because they happen outside of jOOQ's code generation, but you can use Gradle's [source set](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-source-sets) functionality. Since you already have Etienne Studer's third party Gradle plugin in your config (but interestingly aren't actually using it), why not look into [how it enables such configuration for you](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin#configuring-the-jooq-generation-task-to-participate-in-incremental-builds-and-build-caching). That way, you can tell Gradle itself that code doesn't need to be re-generated (though, if you ever do a schema change, jOOQ will then still re-generate *all* the files, not just the "changed" ones, because you apply changes after jOOQ).

Comment: Thank you, but to be honest I didn't understand how to use your recommendations, especially the last 2 links. As for JavaGenerator, I created a custom class extending it in that gradle script, but how do I now tell JOOQ to use it, or just create an instance and run the generatePojoClassFooter method? But which TableDefinition and JavaWriter should I pass there? Sorry, but could you just write a simple example of how to use JavaGenerator in gradle please? I honestly can't figure out how to solve this.

Comment: @man: My answer was meant mostly as a set of pointers to more information, not a step by step tutorial, which would take too long to write. I can answer *specific* follow-up questions (better in question form, than here in the comments, which aren't well suited for complex topics). But I don't know too much about gradle, or Etienne's third party plugin, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer though